# Good way to check who is consuming Thread.interrupted() and not throwing InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, netbeans

I have a big thread that I need to make interrupt-able. This thread uses pieces of 3rd party code and I have no access to their source. Somewhere in all of this code, someone seems to be calling `Thread.interrupted()` and not throwing an exception. I need of a good way to determine who is doing this.

I tried setting breakpoints at `Thread.interrupted()`, but NetBean's conditional breakpoints are not working well. They are stopping at random Threads even though the conditions are not equal to true. This is my breakpoint condition:

```
currentThread().getName().contains("Name of my Thread") == true && currentThread().isInterrupted(false) == true
```

... yet, the debugger stops at the breakpoint even if **none** of these conditions are met. I'm guessing it's getting confused because of the `currentThread()` calls.

Extra info:

- I'm on Java 8
- I'm using Apache NetBeans 11.1.
- I'm using Spring Boot.
- My app is running on a Tomcat server.
- The third-party code I'm using is the Stimulsoft Reports library.
- I'm using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to initiate the thread.
- I'm using `Future.cancel(true)` to send the interrupt signal to the thread.

Comment: Why do you think they're calling `Thread.interrupted()` instead of just swallowing `InterruptedExceptions`?

Comment: Because I put a breakpoint at the InterruptedException constructors and no-one seems to be calling it. I'm going to double check though. (Double checked and the debugger is not stopping at those)